# "Segmentation Fault" at runtime

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
void binarysearch(string key, vector<string>& f2){
sort_vector(f2);

int mid = 0;
int left = 0;
int right = f2.size();
bool found = false;
while (left < right){
    mid = left + (left+right)/2;
    if (key > f2[mid]){ 
        left = mid + 1;
    }
    else if(key < f2[mid]){
        right = mid;
    }
    else{
        found = true;
        left = right;
    }
}
cout << "out of while loop" << endl;
if (found == true){
    cout << "YES: " << key << endl;
}
else{
    cout << " NO: " << key << endl;
}
found = false;
}
```

When I run this, it terminates automatically and says "segmentation fault" with no line number given. What does that even mean and why am I getting this fault?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `std::binary_search` is already available

Comment: You should **learn how to use the debugger**. So enable debugging info and all warnings by compiling with `g++ -Wall -g` and use the `gdb` debugger.... (at least on Linux)

Comment: Please provide the input it's crashing on.

Comment: you are possibly going out of bound, because of the way you have calculated mid. mid=(left+right)/2 and NOT mid=Left +(left+right)/2

Answer (score 5):

A segmentation fault means the program accessed an invalid memory address.  I suspect in this case it's the fact that this:

```
mid = left + (left+right)/2;
```

Leads to a value of mid that's greater than right at some point (since it's effectively the same as `mid = 1.5 * left + 0.5 * right`).  It should be this:

```
mid = left + ( right - left ) / 2;
```

Or, better yet (as long as the sum of left + right does not exceed MAXINT), as mawia suggests:

```
mid = ( left + right ) / 2;
```